# missing ) after argument list, json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running into some issues with my code.  I did a search here, I've checked over my code multiple times and I'm not sure what the issue here is.  I'm not missing any brackets, I'm not seeing any issues with my code so far either.

I'm getting an "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" on line 33.

```
 $(document.ready(function() {

$('#userinput').keyup(function() {
    var userSearch = $(this).val();
    var searchCri = encodeURIComponent(userSearch);
    var ytDirect = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+searchCri+'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';
    //var ytvid = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?q='+searchCri+'&maxResults=1&key={key}';


    $.ajax ({
        type: "GET",
        url: ytDirect,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.data.items) {
                $.each(response.data.items, function(data) {
                    var videoId = data.id;
                    var videoTitle = data.title;
                    var videoHits = data.viewCount;
                    var vidbox = "<iframe width='640' height='385' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+videoId+"'frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";
                    var vidResult = "<div id = 'result'>"+vidbox+"</div>";
                    $('#result').html(vidResult);
                });
            }

        }

    });

});



});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Define *multiple times*. `$(document).ready(...)`. You're missing a `)` after `(document`.

Comment: Or just do `$(function() { ... }`.

Comment: Try writing $(function () { ...

Comment: I don't think the question deserves down votes. Many beginners can make simple syntax errors and need help. Isn't that what this site is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John B. Mentioned as the first comment. At the first line of the snippet you have a syntax error:

Change

```
$(document.ready(function() {
```

To

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: Welp.  Thanks guys.  Now I'm getting "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  I don't know if this is a jQuery fluke or if it's a beginner fluke on my part.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the file? It could be many things. You could be referencing jQuery wrong or double including jQuery, which are the 2 most common reasons for that error IMHO. You can also try Dennis R. suggestion and use $(function() { instead of $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  I'd linked my script before the jQuery script, a mistake I won't be making again in the future.  Thanks again for the help everyone, I appreciate it.